# Combinatorics Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, combinatorics

I've come across an interesting programming problem that I can't seem to formulate a solution to. Suppose you have K balls of N different colors. You must partition all of the balls into as many groups as possible such that no two groups are the same. (Two groups are considered the same if they have the same number of balls of each color.) What is the maximum number of groups you can make?

constraints:
1<=K<=50,
1<=N<=14

To clarify: We would like an algorithm that takes in an array of integers >= 1. The size of the array is N and the sum of the values it contains is K. The algorithm should return the maximum number of groups.

Any ideas on an algorithmic approach to this problem?

Comment: Would Red/Blue and Blue/Red count as being the same group?

Comment: @RoryDaulton I've changed the wording to be more clear. Hopefully it is more understandable now. Two groups are considered the same if they have the same number of balls of each color.

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz yes they would be considered the same

Comment: Looks like K is your limiting factor, so let N=14. Then you've got 1 group for the empty set, 14 one-colour groups, 18 two-colour groups, and then you've hit your limit.

Comment: I wonder if it is enough to use a greedy algorithm?  i.e. take all size 1 groups, then size 2 groups, etc.  Probably best within a size category to use groups with as many of different colours first to keep most options open.

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz I believe it is always optimal to take all one ball groups possible. Perhaps it is always better to take a size X group before a size (X+1) group, but the problem of selecting which balls to put into that group still remains.

Comment: Out of curiousity, where do you come across a programming question like this? :-)

Comment: @RoryDaulton thanks, that edit is good.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein It was proposed to me by a professor of mine who is also trying to solve it.

Comment: Heh.  If I were to guess, that means your professor is trying to crowd source a google foobar question to the class.  This feels very much like many of the foobar questions.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein I've never heard of a foobar question, what is that? And we discussed this personally, it wasn't crowdsourced to the class.

Comment: It's one of their semi-secret hiring processes.  (See [here](https://thehustle.co/the-secret-google-interview-that-landed-me-a-job) among other places.)  When you make the right searches, you get invited to take coding challenges.  They start out easy, and end up like this.  I only got to level 4 of 5, but many of their questions deal with multi-variable combinatorics.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147760/discussion-between-user2659185-and-scott-mermelstein).

Comment: Does "K balls of N different colors" mean that you have a *total* of K balls? Or do you have `K*N` total balls?

Comment: @JimMischel there is a total of K balls

Comment: K balls, N different colors, but we don't know how many of each color?

Comment: I also want to know how many balls *of each colour* we have.  Anyway, there exist situations where we are forced to skip one or more group sizes: e.g. if K=4 and N=1, the optimal solution has 1 group of size 1 and 1 group of size 3 (and the only other valid solution has 1 group of size 4).

Comment: @JimMischel I'm guessing the input will be of the form "rrggggbccmyyyyyykk".

Comment: I think N is upper bound as you can have at most N groups with 1 ball in each group? Then does something like greedy + brute force to test if `x` group is feasible where `x` <= N?  :/

Comment: @m69: I'd rather not have to guess.

Comment: @JimMischel If the input is simply N=44, K=5, then the best case (23) and worst case (8) are easily calculated, and it's not much of a question.

Comment: Can you give some examples?

Comment: @ScottMermelstein Too bad I never *google* for terms like that…

Comment: @user2659185 If your professor likes my solution, he can invite me to writing a paper on it :-) Does the problem have a well-known name already?

Comment: Lemma: For N >= K+2, there is an optimal solution with K groups of size 1 (one per color). Say G is an optimal set of groups for a given K and N. Suppose c is one of our K colors, and that c doesn't appear in any group of size 1 in G. Find any group X in G that contains a ball of color c. Move c to its own group. Now, we know X - c is identical to some other group in G because G was maximal. Move the balls of X - c to the the largest of the remaining groups (which we know is of size >= 2, thus doesn't reduce the number of single-ball groups).

Comment: @DaveGalvin In the question K is balls, N is colours (should be other way round, I agree). If an algorithm adds any leftover balls to a random group, then you  can consider a solution for K=N+1 to have single ball groups of every colour too.

Comment: @m69 Counterexample for K=N+1: Two balls of the same color. K=N+2 guarantees that there's always some group of size >1 to add leftover balls to. Thanks for the K vs N correction -- It seems I can't update the lemma comment; maybe too much time has passed. Hopefully it's clear to everyone.

Comment: @DaveGalvin I think we're only disagreeing on semantics. I'd consider RR -> R (R) -> RR to be a 1-ball group solution, albeit with an added leftover ball, as I explain in my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After speaking with my professor again, I learned that this was an adaptation of an open.kattis.com [problem](https://open.kattis.com/problems/listgame2).

The two are nearly identical, as any instance of the original problem can be solved by taking the prime factorization of N and treating each prime factor as a ball. For instance, 900 = 2^2*3^2*5*2, so the equivalent balls problem would be 2 2 2.

The given bounds were found using the max bound of 10^15. 2^50 > 10^15, so there can never be more than 50 factors, and multiplying the first 15 primes by each other also exceed 10^15, meaning there can be at most 14 groups.

The tradeoff between number of balls and number of groups was overlooked however, and that in my opinion makes the problem much easier to solve. For instance, if there are 14 groups, there will only be 1 ball in each group, while if there are 50 balls then they will all belong to the same group (this is due to the 10^15 constraints of the original problem)

With this new information I was able to solve the problem. I factorized N into a list of Primes as well as a list of all factors, and then used a multiple dimensional knapsack algorithm(if N has X unique prime factors, then the knapsack DP will be X+1 dimensional, where the first dimension is which item you are considering and each other dimension represents your remaining supply of a certain prime factor). Each factor of N would represent a potential item to take in the knapsack, with it's prime factorization being it's cost vector.

After doing this, the problem was still too slow on maximum cases, and one additional optimization was required. I found that an optimal solution always exists that uses as many single ball groups as possible. By creating as many 1 ball groups as possible in the beginning and solving the remaining subproblem, I was able to complete the problem in Kattis's time constraints.

My algorithm depends on two assumptions that I have proven:

1. If you can make X groups without using all of the balls, you can also make X groups using all of the balls. This makes knapsack solutions where you don't use 100% of the capacity valid. This assumption can be proven by taking all unused balls and adding them all to the largest group. This will create a group larger than any other, and hence it must be unique. This leaves you with the same number of groups, but all balls utilized.
2. there always exists an optimal solution using as many 1-ball groups as possible. This makes it possible to reduce the original problem into a subproblem solvable in the time constraint. This can be proven as well. Take any optimal solution. For any 1 ball grouping that does not exist, take a group containing that 1 ball, and move every other ball in that group to the largest group. This creates a solution with the same (optimal) number of groups, that also has as many 1 ball groups as possible.

My solution has a runtime of O(F(N)^2), where F(N) is the total number of factors of N.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to explain. I wasn't really getting close to a solution, and I don't have much time at the moment. Btw, can you post a list of inputs and results, so that people who come up with a working algorithm can check their results?

Comment: Is 10^15 also part of this problem statement? If yes, can you edit this into the question so this answer makes more sense? If it's not relevant to this problem, but rather only to the one you linked, why is it included here?

Answer (score 1):

*(I was trying to formulate a game strategy, but I kept running into counter-examples, so I've re-written the answer, keeping only those bits that seemed to be working.)*

**Input**

I will assume that the input is of the form:

```
{K:30, N:6, red:4, green:3, blue:1, cyan:10, magenta:5, yellow:7}
```

which can also be written as:

```
rrrr ggg b cccccccccc mmmmm yyyyyyy
```

**Single-ball groups**

A first observation is that a single ball can only turn one invalid (duplicate) group into one valid (unique) group, so by not using the single ball to form a one-ball group you can only gain one group, so you might as well start by creating one-ball groups of every available colour.

```
r g gg ggg (ggg) = 4  
  g gg ggg rggg  = 4
```

```
r g b bb bbb bbbbbb     = 6
r g b bb bbb bbbb (bb)  = 6
    b bb bbb bbbb rb gb = 6
```

This effectively turns input with K balls of N colours into a problem with K-N balls of N or fewer colours, with a maximum of 49:1, 48:2 ... 36:14. The example mentioned above is reduced from 30:6 to 24:5

```
rrrr ggg b cccccccccc mmmmm yyyyyyy  
r g b c m y  +  rrr gg ccccccccc mmmm yyyyyy
```

**Small-to-large groups**

If you create as many S-sized groups as possible before moving on to size S+1, and you have S unused balls left, they will form a duplicate S-sized group, but if there was a way to avoid this, you'd have one more S-sized group, so that would mean that the solution for S-sized groups wasn't optimal in the first place.

If you create as many S-sized groups as possible before moving on to size S+1, and you have more than S unused balls left, the larger groups you form with them will never be duplicates of S-sized groups.

It is tempting to assume from this that creating single-ball groups, then 2-ball groups, then 3-ball groups ... will lead to the optimal solution. However, there examples where it doesn't:

```
{K:45, N:5, red:3, green:3, blue:3, cyan:3, yellow:33}  
rrr ggg bbb ccc yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

```
r g b c y                         =  5  
rg bc ry gy by cy yy              =  7  
yyy yyyy yyyyy yyyyyy yyyyyyy (y) =  5
                            TOTAL = 17
```

```
r g b c y                         =  5  
      ry gy by cy yy              =  5  
ryy gyy byy cyy                   =  4  
yyy yyyy yyyyy yyyyyy             =  4  
                            TOTAL = 18
```

---

It seems that this is where the 50 balls maximum comes into play. If you start out by making the largest possible number of 1-ball groups, then 2, 3 ... it is possible that you have to break up a smaller group to turn leftover balls (or a unique group + leftover balls) into two or more unique groups. However, is seems impossible to improve a solution with no leftover balls, at least with this input size limit.

---

Finding the optimal number of 2-sized groups means filling a 2D table like this:

```
   r  g  b  c  m  y
r  +
g  +  -
b  +  -  +
c  -  +  -  -
m  +  +  -  +  +
y  -  +  +  -  -  +
```

There are 1 + 2 + ... + N possible groups, but that doesn't mean that there are 2 ^ (1 + 2 + ... + N) options to consider. One the one hand, we're looking for the optimal solution, so there's no point looking at solutions with only a few groups, and on the other hand, after making 1-ball groups, there is a maximum of K - N balls left to make groups with. There's also the fact that some colours may not have N + 1 balls, so not all combinations with that colour can be made at the same time; in fact it becomes impossible to create all 2-ball combinations when using more than 6 colours:

```
 N   K-N   pairs  combi

 1    49    24      1
 2    48    24      3
 3    47    23      6
 4    46    23     10
 5    45    22     15
 6    44    22     21
 7    43    21     28
 8    42    21     36
 9    41    20     45
10    40    20     55
11    39    19     66
12    38    19     78
13    37    18     91
14    36    18    105
```

Comment: It's possible that in step 3 and 4, you should not make combinations that have more Y's than X's, and leave those for when Y has become the most abundant colour.

Comment: Can you prove that this approach will lead to creating maximum number of groups?

Comment: @PhamTrung Not really; it's based on a few observations while trying out examples, but it probably needs more work. I haven't really tacled how to form groups with more than two colours yet. If someone writes brute-force code or another method we'll be able to compare results.

Comment: I'm not sure about step 4. Will this ever generate groups like `rgb`, with more than two different colors?

Comment: If we start with `rrrrr bbbbb ggg` what stops us from winding up at `r b g rr bb gg rb` with `rb` left over?  (The right answer being, of course, `r b g rr bb rb rg gb`.)

Comment: @Bergi That is indeed one of the things that still needs addressing; I'm not quite there yet.

Comment: @btilly Good example; I'm still working on the details of step 3 and 4, as I mentioned in a comment above this. I think the example proves that when several colours have the same number of balls, you can't just choose randomly what to do. It goes to `r b g rr bb + rrbbgg` and then gg would be the wrong move, but other moves lead to the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with K single-element groups and refine them step-by-step until all groups are distinct. In every step, we remove two groups, join them and put the new group back. The difficulty is which groups to choose, and I would suggest the following factors for ordering the choices (in descending order of importance):

1. The more distinct result wins (e.g. two groups that combine to a new distinct group over two groups that combine to an already known one)
2. The smaller result wins (e.g. two-element groups over three-element groups)
3. The most common groups to remove

I'm not sure whether you need to brute-force all combinations when there are multiple choices which two groups to select and join, or whether taking any path will lead to an optimal solution already, but when we need to try multiple ones a dynamic programming approach will be necessary to limit the state explosion.

Examples (each row ordered by number of occurrences):

```
b  g-g-g  r-r-r-r  m-m-m-m-m  y-y-y-y-y-y-y  c-c-c-c-c-c-c-c-c-c
b  cc  g-g-g  r-r-r-r  m-m-m-m-m  y-y-y-y-y-y-y  c-c-c-c-c-c-c-c
b  cc  cy  g-g-g  r-r-r-r  m-m-m-m-m  y-y-y-y-y-y  c-c-c-c-c-c-c
b  cc  cy  cm  g-g-g  r-r-r-r  m-m-m-m  y-y-y-y-y-y  c-c-c-c-c-c
b  cc  cy  cm  yy  g-g-g  r-r-r-r  m-m-m-m  y-y-y-y  c-c-c-c-c-c
b  cc  cy  cm  yy  cr  g-g-g  r-r-r  m-m-m-m  y-y-y-y  c-c-c-c-c
b  cc  cy  cm  yy  cr  cg  g-g  r-r-r  m-m-m-m  y-y-y-y  c-c-c-c
b  cc  cy  cm  yy  cr  cg  my  g-g  r-r-r  m-m-m  y-y-y  c-c-c-c
b  cc  cy  cm  yy  cr  cg  my  rm  g-g  r-r  m-m  y-y-y  c-c-c-c
b  cc  cy  cm  yy  cr  cg  my  rm  g  yg  r-r  m-m  y-y  c-c-c-c
b  cc  cy  cm  yy  cr  cg  my  rm  g  yg  r  y  ry  m-m  c-c-c-c
b  cy  cm  yy  cr  cg  my  rm  g  yg  r  y  ry  m-m  cc-cc  c-c
b  cy  cm  yy  cr  cg  my  rm  g  yg  r  y  ry  m  cc  mcc  c-c
cy  cm  yy  cr  cg  my  rm  g  yg  r  y  ry  m  cc  mcc  c  cb
```

```
g-g-g  r-r-r-r-r  b-b-b-b-b
rb  g-g-g  r-r-r-r  b-b-b-b
rb  rg  g-g  r-r-r  b-b-b-b
rb  rg  br  g  r-r-r  b-b-b
rb  rg  br  g  r  rr  b-b-b
rb  rg  br  g  r  rr  b  bb
```

As an algorithm for each step, I did not generate all possible combinations of groups to remove and ordered them by the comparison function above, but went backwards to get some candidates:

1. choose the most common group and remove one, then choose the (now) most common group and remove one
2. look that they together don't have more elements than what could be achieved with less common groups
3. look that they combine to an unknown group
4. If so, take them, if not then repeat from step 1 with the next-common groups

This basically asks the questions

- How common is this group (combination of elements) / what is its number of occurences?
- Are all possible combinations with elements from this group below a certain size already generated?
- Are possible combinations with elements from this group and elements from the next groups already generated?

whose results can be cached in a dynamic-programming-like fashion so that we can quickly skip some candidates (until there is really no good choice and we have to perform a merge that does not generate a new distinct group, seen in the above example when the line gets shorter). We also can assume that we basically never select a group which occurs only once, as that would be known not to generate a result with more distinct groups.